# compress gzip file issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, compression, gzip

I'm currently using jszip and zipping the files, but the files are broken because i zip it as a zip file.
but the backend can unzip only gzip files.
I'm using vue js for my front end.

```
                   let zip = new jszip();
                    zip.file(fileToCompress.name, fileToCompress);
                    let component = this;

                    zip.generateAsync({type: "blob", compression: "DEFLATE"}).then(function(zipedFile) {
send to the back end
}
```

how can i zip it as a gzip ? is there library that i can use ? or i can use some how jszip? if i can, how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `pako` package, it supports `gzip`. See [gzip method](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/#gzip)

> gzip(data[, options]) ->  Uint8Array

Comment: i have found this as well but i can't see the metadata

Comment: What do you mean? Compression level or something else?

Comment: actually i did get all the metadata but i've got still a broken file